# Batch File Self Extracting Zip

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I am using 7zip to create a self extracting zip file. When I run the .exe it extracts things into the directory where the .exe was fired off like I want. But is there a way to always overwrite instead of seeing the prompt screen asking you?

I did read that -aoa or-y may be my answer, but I could not get them to work.

```
@echo off
set PATH=%PATH%;Y:\Program Files\7-Zip\

set branchPath=Z:\XP_Processes\branch\%1\
set dwcltrn=DWCLTRN.DBF
set dwemptrn=DWEMPTRN.DBF
set dwhist=DWHIST.DBF

echo %branchPath%

cd /d %branchPath%

7z a -sfx "Z:\XP_Processes\%1.exe" %dwcltrn%
7z a -sfx "Z:\XP_Processes\%1.exe" %dwemptrn%
7z a -sfx "Z:\XP_Processes\%1.exe" %dwhist%
```

Answer (score 1):

Type in Start - All Programs - Accessories - Run

```
iexpress
```

Follow prompts to add your files.

Run the program you just made

```
"C:\Users\Fred\test.EXE" /Q /T:c:\users
```

Answer (score 0):

Try launching your SFX file like so: `myfile.exe -y`